# How to know how many users "like" something [facebook]

Tags: facebook

How to get how many times specific object was liked?
*Answer*: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat

and

How to get the most liked links in my application?

**UPD 3**: another question then: how to get the `object_id` for given liked page
*Answer*: `object_url` fql table

Comment: According to a recent read, that is - or soon to become a meaningless number as facebook is on a campaign to have everyone like everything from everywhere. This article only makes mention of the phenomenon and I've not looked into it further: https://www.adbusters.org/blogs/blackspot-blog/myspacing-facebook.html (Yeah, it's a pretty leftist source, but that doesn't make the factual claims false.)

Comment: @msw, whatever - it is what I need in now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a SQL (FQL) query and then count the users who liked the object. Heres information on the query: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like

Comment: yeah, i did it and it always return nothing

Comment: @omizzle: i took the query sample from the page you pasted `SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id="122706168308"` and tried to quyery it on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query

Comment: thanks, i got the user list. is it possible now to count them?

Comment: If its an array then you simply count the items (ids) in the array.

Comment: @omizzle: and if it is 200k of users there? :-S

Comment: You will still have to count through the separate items in that array with whatever programming language you are using. There should be different methods to do so efficiently in the language.